# LWJGL Get Display Size Not Working Correctly

Tags: java, opengl, resize, lwjgl, slick2d

```
Draw.drawSquare(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), UITextures.engineBackgroundTex);
```

For some reason, the texture is the same size, even after the window is resized.

`Display.setResizable` is set to `true`.

Am I correctly getting the size of the display?

ALSO: The draw call is running at 60 fps and `Draw.drawSquare` has been tested to work, but for some reason `Display.getWidth` does not work to resize the texture...

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `Display.getWidth()` states:

> This value will be updated after a call to Display.update().